# What is the sponsored party called?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Google results for *sponsee* have scattered definitions in unreliable sources, so it does not appear that is a real word. I'm looking for something similar, a single word.

The specific context is a social group membership application where new members must be sponsored (as in definition 2, here - "one who assumes responsibility for some other person or thing") by existing members. I am looking for a single word to describe the target of such a sponsorship. I am about to sponsor a fraternity, but I would like to have a more general word for what I'm sponsoring. Next time, the fraternity could well be a study club, or something else.

Therefore, what is the sponsored party also called? E.g. if I sponsor somebody, that person is my **__**?

Comment: [Sponsee](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=106160) "`is unnecessary, and abhorrent in form... As a corollary, anyone who uses either of these words will immediately be plonked into the category "illiterate philistine".`"

Comment: If the sponsored party is a single individual, and only you or a very small number of sponsors are bankrolling him, he'd be your [protege](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Protege). For more broad-based arrangements, I think most people would just say your fraternity, for example, is a [pet project](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pet_project)

Comment: @FumbleFingers *protégé, protégée* != **protège*

Comment: @tchrist: Yeah, I know all those. But they're for *French* people. I don't normally do accents on *English* words.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That’s why I starred the verb inflection, because it is French not English.  The others are English.

Comment: @tchrist: I even knew that was what you meant. My point is I don't consider the accents to be necessary (or indeed, *desirable*) if we're going to call them English words.

Comment: @FumbleFingers When the source language a word is borrowed from uses the Latin script with diacritics or an alternate set of orthographic conventions to signal a change in pronunciation, then you have only two reasonable choices: you either retain the original as is, or else you respell it to fit English norms. What you should ***not*** do is pull in a foreign word that uses different conventions and strip out the necessary markings, because then you add senseless new exceptions. For example: *naïve* doesn’t rhyme with *waive*, nor *façade* with *arcade*, nor *jalapeños* with *hollow penis*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But I have nothing against the respellings of *halapenyos, fassade, nayeve* — since those now fit into the English system. If you find yourself incapable of taking the trouble to write the word under the rules that make its pronunciation work in the language of origin, then the least you can do is respell the darned thing so that people know how to say it in English.

Comment: @tchrist: Tell it to the judge (and jury and executioner, which in this case is the great mass of people who *write* English). Most people already don't bother with accents in *naive, facade, cafe, arete, debacle,* etc. And they're increasingly doing the same with *protege*, which is fine by me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think not. As it ever has been and ever shall be, there is a distinction to be made between “most people” and educated writers who don’t care to look like bumpkins.  Perhaps you prefer bumpkins; I prefer not to come across as uneducated.

Comment: @tchrist: Fair enough. Just be careful not to come across as a pompous reactionary die-hard! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers If you had had your way, we’d’ve been stuck with the *Grand Canon* instead of the *Grand Canyon* for that particular *cañón*, which I’m sure even you will see as infinitely superior for a canonical transliteration.  After all, a Grand Canon would be like a Great Fugue, but less interesting.

Comment: @tchrist: *If I had my way* we'd all be speaking (and *writing*) like [Russell Hoban's *Riddley Walker*](http://www.theguardian.com/books/2010/nov/13/riddley-walker-russell-hoban-bookclub). But I'm just trying to be *realistic*, about what's gonna happen whether you/I/we like it or not.

Answer (score 9):

Sounds like a *beneficiary*.

It's a reasonably broad term, but sponsoring is similarly broad.

Comment: Especially if the sponsorship involves financial support.

Answer (score 5):

In the section of their Consolidated Code regarding [sponsorship](http://www.codescentre.com/index.php/icc-code/chapter-b-sponsorship), the International Chamber of Commerce sticks to *sponsored party*.

Apparently, they wanted to avoid hideous neologisms like *sponsee* -- which isn't even in my Merriam-Webster Unabridged.

Answer (score 3):

*Protégé* would appear to fit the bill. OED:

> A person (sometimes *spec.* a boy or man) who receives the protection or patronage of another; a person who is guided and supported by someone with greater experience or influence. Also in extended use.

The bit about “(sometimes *spec.* a boy or man)” has to do with the word’s French and gendered character: the feminine form would be *protégée.*

This word also serves as counterpart to *mentor;* attempts to substitute *telemachus* for that function have gone nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

Go with *beneficiary*. Google's NGram indicates that since 1800 it has both *sponsee* and *protoge* beat "hands down" (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=beneficiary%2Csponsee%2Cprotoge&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbeneficiary%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csponsee%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprotoge%3B%2Cc0).

Any adult will understand what you mean.

Comment: This was already given as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

If tutor, then tutee is acceptable, then sponsor, sponsee seems like it should be. Granted, they both sound silly, but what else you gonna call it?